# .net c# regex pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i have some strings that are like:

```
abc_f25f_xxxxx.gif
vcvbn_te4we_dsfg
q12_f4wse_brff
```

what i need is to write the pattern to extract only the first and second part of string, than

```
abc_f25f
vcvbn_te4we
q12_f4wse
```

Comment: ^[a-z0-9A-Z]+[_][a-z0-9A-Z]+

Comment: Hi there, You have many good sites out there  for trying out regex patterns. one of them is https://regex101.com/. It has also explanations of the various regex elements. I suggest that you try there first.

Comment: .*?_.*?(?=_) https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: yes,  i tried on regex101.com, but i can t find my pattern...

Answer (score -2):

\b([a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]*_)

[begin] followed by [alphanumeric] followed by [underscore]  followed by [alphanumeric]  followed by [underscore]

Comment: It would be helpful to add some extra information to help explain the regex.